# Is it possible to create flv player's wrapper using AS3 and FlashDevelop only?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flex3, flashdevelop

Is it possible to create flv player's(mainly YouTube Player's) wrapper using AS3 and FlashDevelop only? I am concerned about it because I don't have Flash authoring environment. I have seen many tutorials and in first step (in all of them) are asking to create a .fla file. If you know about it and if it is possible then please let me know. Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated otherwise I'm stuck.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely - I've not used Flash Develop, but I assume it has the ability to compile built in, right?

You can even get more stripped down - all you need is a single ".as" file and you can manually run MXMLC (the Open Source AS3 compiler) to create your .swf. I dug up a tutorial for you here, this should help: http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/as3withmxmlc/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, you can create pure actionscript projects without the Flash IDE.
You can create a project with just .as files and compile the swf out of it.

You could load the graphics externally, for example loading jpg's runtime, or you can embed them. Or you could draw the interface with actionscript.